# How to change KDE shortcut for showing all virtual desktops?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde-plasma, virtual-desktop

On an old computer running KUbuntu 17.10 (that's KDE + Ubuntu 17.10), somehow, I changed the keyboard shortcut for showing all desktop windows. (The default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.)

I just installed the same OS on a new computer, and cannot for the life of me figure out how I changed that shortcut. A lot of Googling hasn't gotten me any closer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it. The magic phrase is "desktop grid", and it is found under `System Settings -> Desktop Behavior -> Desktop Effects`. (Everything else having to do with virtual desktops is found under `System Settings -> Desktop Behavior -> Virtual Desktops`.)